# Spread operator is not working on Add To Cart function in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I am trying to add the product into cart via React & Redux, here is my state functionality

**Initial state**

```
const initialState = {
    error: false,
    products: [],
    addedItems: [],
    total: 0
}
```

**Add to cart function**

```
case actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
    let addedItem = state.products.find(item => item._id == action.id)
    let existed_item 
    if(state.addedItems){
        existed_item = state.addedItems.filter(item => action._id == item.id)
    }
    if(existed_item){
        addedItem.quantity += 1
        return {
            ...state,
            total: state.total + parseFloat(addedItem.price)
        }
    } else {
        addedItem.quantity = 1;
        let newTotal = state.total + parseFloat(addedItem.price)
        return {
            ...state,
            ...{addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem]}, //error in here
            total: newTotal
        }
    }
```

But showing this below error:

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
> In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

I also tried like this

```
...{addedItems: [...(initialState.addedItems), addedItem]}
```

and it only adds one item to the cart, not pushing a new item.

What I have done wrong here? I really not understanding for almost 3 hours.

I really appreciate it if you help me.

Thanks

Comment: its not clear what `state` exactly is !!!

Comment: why spearding {addedItems...} again, you can directly write
  `return {...state, addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem]}`.

Comment: @p2pdops I have tried like this but showing error like this image [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17hxngxgIZfhNdJsn79lf8DswtkaDwKz4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ho.. easy now just change to `{.. , addedItems: [...(state.addedItems), addedItem]}`

Comment: @p2pdops I have tried like this `...{addedItems: [...(initialState.addedItems), addedItem]}` and it only adds one item to the cart, not pushing any new item!

Comment: Yes because `initialState.addedItems` is always empty array, and never gets modified.. that should be `state.addedItems`

Answer (score 0):

First, the outside spread opearator is not needed.
Second, you are trying to put addedItems in an object , however its a part of initialState and not a part of nested object inside initialState.

So this is what you want,

```
return {
            ...state,
            addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem], 
            total: newTotal
        }
```

```js
const initialState = {
  error: false,
  products: [],
  addedItems: [],
  total: 0
}

let result = {
  ...initialState,
  addedItems: [...initialState.addedItems, 1],
  total: 1
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: After adding this it's showing like this [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17hxngxgIZfhNdJsn79lf8DswtkaDwKz4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It seems that the issue is somewhere else. You can try the code above and see that it works.

Comment: I have tried like this `...{addedItems: [...initialState.addedItems, addedItem]}` but it's only adding one item

Comment: Yes, it will add only "addedItem", and it's expected. I think there is some confusion regarding what yo want to achieve exactly, since as per the question, spread operator wasn't working, but now its working. Maybe you want to edit the question :)

Comment: I want to add to cart more than one item, my previous project was like `addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem]` and it is working but in that project, it's not!